# Do these relations hold between the four-gradient and its inverse?

Tags: special-relativity, operators, differentiation

Does it make sense to write the following expression:

$$F_{\alpha\beta}(x) :=\partial_\alpha\ \left( \partial^{-1} \right)_\beta f(x), \tag{1}$$

with $\partial_\mu := \partial/\partial x^\mu$, $\partial^{-1}$ the inverse operator of $\partial$ and $f$ some function of $x$? I am not sure how to define $\partial^{-1}$, hence I assume that it satisfies the usual relation for inverse operators (when they exist):

$$\mathcal{O} \mathcal{O}^{-1} = \mathbb{1}. \tag{2}$$

Of course that holds only if $\mathcal{O}$ is reversible (is $\partial$ reversible? I guess yes).

Then does it make sense to interpret $(1)$ as:

$$F_{\alpha\beta}(x) \overset{?}{=} \eta_{\alpha\beta} f(x) \tag{3}$$

with $\eta$ the metric? Note that I have replaced the Euclidean $\mathbb{1}$ of eq. $(2)$ by a "Minkowski $\mathbb{1}$", i.e. $\text{diag}(-1,1,1,...,1)$. If $(3)$ makes sense, then in $4$ dimensional Minkowski space we would have:

$$F^{\alpha}_{\ \ \ \alpha} (x) = 4 f(x), \tag{4}$$

right? If all above is wrong, then how can the inverse of the four gradient be defined rigorously?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What do you mean by the inverse of the gradient? Is $g$ or $\eta$ the metric? Why would (1) and (2) be the same?

Comment: @Javier I have tried to address your comments in the last edit of my question. Note that I have renamed $g$ with $F$ in order to avoid confusion with the metric.

Comment: So to clarify, you're asking whether there is an operator $\partial^{-1}$ with $\partial_\alpha \partial^{-1}_\beta f = \eta_{\alpha\beta} f$, right?

Comment: @Javier Right, I guess it boils down to that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible, because the derivative can not be inverted. For example, if you have a function $f(x)=x+1$ then its derivative is $f'(x)=1$. Now, if you try to invert the derivative (which means finding the primitive) you will see there you get the original function only up to an arbitrary constant ${\cal C}$
$$\int f'(x) dx = f(x) + {\cal C}.$$ In other words, there is an infinity of functions having the same derivative.